# Automatically Refactor Access Modifiers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, access-modifiers

Is there a tool that can run through a visual studio solution and adjust access modifiers to anything not being called in the solution is converted to private or internal where applicable?

I suppose I could just change everything to private, and then use the compiler messages and do it by hand...but that could take a while, if there was something automatic, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) you can analyze your code for stuff like this. It has a SQL-like query language where you can select all the members that are public and could be internal or private, like this:

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE CouldBeInternal
SELECT METHODS WHERE CouldBePrivate
```

EDIT: See this blog post about [Optimal Encapsulation](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2007/10/31/optimal-encapsulation.aspx).

Comment: This is not free, and it's only a query. Are there any tools free? Change them automatically? Maybe Roslyn can do this job much easier?